# Как сделать чтобы количество select стало равно цифры введённой в input

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такую функцию
Есть код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  введите число: <input type="number"><br/>
  <select>
  <option value="1">Строка</option>
 </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Как сделать чтобы количество select стало равно цифры введённой в input
Допустим если я ввел в input число 2, то содержимое select отобразилось два раза на странице, сразу, без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: количество селектов или же количество опций в селекте?

Comment: количество селектов

Comment: Т.е. количество селектов с одним `option` равное числу введеному в инпуте? Уверен?

Comment: input = 2
<select>Содержимое</select>
<select>Содержимое</select>
Если
input = 3
<select>Содержимое</select>
<select>Содержимое</select>
<select>Содержимое</select>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  введите число: <input type="number"><br/>
  
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input').on('keyup change', function(){
    var inputvalue = $(this).val();
    $('select').remove();
    for(i = 0; i< inputvalue; i++){
        $('body').append($('<select><option>Содержимое</option></select>'))
    }
});

});

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```js
function selects(val) {
  $('select.clone').remove();
  for (var i = 1; i < val; i++) {
    $('select.original').clone().removeClass('original').addClass('clone').appendTo('body');
  }
}

$('.number').on('change', function() {
  selects(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
введите число: <input class="number" type="number"><br/>
<select class="original">
  <option value="1">Строка</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = $(this).val();
    var $select = $('select');
    var $content = $('.content');

    $content.html('');

    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      $content.append($select[0].outerHTML);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 число: <input type="number"><br/>
 <div class="content">
    <select>
      <option value="1">Строка</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```